# Filter CSV using .txt list of values

Tags: powershell, csv

I have about 100 CSVs that I need to filter through, with the desired ouptut being all rows where the 'First Name' and 'Last Name' fields match a list that I have. Unfortunately, since the list I'm searching from was made separately and by hand there is no unique identifier or key beyond the combination of first and last name (I have street addresses but they are written in a different format than the CSVs).

What I've tried:

```
$myinput = Get-Content 'C:\folder\names.txt'
Import-Csv 'C:\folder\mycsv1.csv' | Where {
  $myimput -match $_.'Last Name' -and
  $myinput -match $_.'First_Name'
} | Out-File 'C:\folder\results.txt'
```

I get a blank .txt.  When I tried again without the `Out-File` I got no output in PowerShell.

Also, If there is a way to automate this with all 100 CSVs, that would be VERY helpful.  Any recommendations?

Comment: I recommend you change `imput` to `input`

Comment: can you put an example of content to names.txt

Answer (score 0):

you have an error into imput, try Something like this for search into all csv (if all csv have same columns) :

```
$ListNames=get-content "c:\temp2\names.txt"
$dircsv="c:\temp2\"
$PathResultFile="c:\temp\result.csv"

gci $dircsv -file -filter "*.csv" | %{
import-csv $_.FullName | where {$csvrow=$_; ($ListNames | where {$_ -match $csvrow.'Last Name' -and $_ -match $csvrow.'First_Name'}).count -gt 0 } 
} | export-csv $PathResultFile -NoType
```

Comment: Where do `$csvrow.Documentnummer` and `$csvrow.Versie` stem from?

Comment: Bad copy paste ty :)